# Unable to execute Import-Module Azure PowerShell Command

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying to import Azure module from Azure using windows powershell but I am facing the following error

> The following error occurred while loading the extended type data
>   file: , C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Azure\5.3.0\Services\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Websites.Types.ps1xml:
>   The file was skipped because of the following validation exception:
>   File C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Azure\5.3.0\Services\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Websites.Types.ps1xml
>   cannot be loaded because its operation is blocked by software
>   restriction policies, such as those created by using Group Policy

any help please.

Comment: try `set-executionpolicy unrestricted` before doing the import

Comment: it did not work even after executing gpupdate /force

Comment: Did you try to execute the script in powershell as "run as administrator"

Comment: yes I did that.

Comment: Maybe the file is marked 'Blocked' like Windows does with files downloaded from internet? How about shutting the viruskiller down for test. Does that have any efect?